# Python Selenium - disable chrome tab sleeping/hibernation

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

After my selenium runs for a while, chrome will 'hibernate' the tab if I don't manually interact with it and my code will give
`selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchWindowException: Message: no such window: window was already closed`

Are there any options or chrome extensions to stop chrome from putting my tabs to sleep?